# Get top results by SUM column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to write following SQL in rails (via ActiveRecord) and having no luck. SQL is following end as such works:

```
select main_section_id, district_id, sum(answer)
from section_inputs
where year = 2012
and main_section_id= 2 
group by main_section_id, district_id 
order by 3 desc
limit 5
```

I think that column names are descriptive, in any case following Rails conventions. To sum the problem up, I am trying to get top 5 `Districts` for specific `MainSection`, *answer* column here is integer which represents my score system.

I know question is little too specific (doing my job for me), but I really hit the wall here and if asking for solution is too much some guidance would be great help as well.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the existing query? Not giving expected results?

Comment: It is working, I am trying to write it using Rails syntax. e.g. SectionInput.where(:year => 2012, :main_sections_id => 2) .... and I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SectionInput.select([:main_section_id, :district_id, 'sum(answer) as  total']).where(:year=>2012).where(:main_section_id=>2).group(:main_section_id).group(:district_id).order('3 desc').limit(5)
```

Else, you can directly include the sql to run

```
SectionInput.find_all_by_sql('select main_section_id, district_id,
sum(answer) from section_inputs where year = 2012 and main_section_id=
2  group by main_section_id, district_id  order by 3 desc limit 5')
```

Also, look at the guide to see all [Rails 3 querying basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly I just grouped `where` and `group` statements. If you comma separate them it is same as conjunction. Great help and snippet I will go back many times.